# tableView Cells only populate in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have created an app that uses a tableViewController, and populates its cells from the contents of .plist file. I thought my app worked perfectly until I attempted to build it to my iPhone. It turns out my cells will only populate while running in the simulator, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Here are some screen shots of the problem.

[image: App Running in Simulator]

[image: On iPhone]

[image]

I know this is something that it probably a simple fix but I can't quite get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout your file name and in your code that reads the plist file. Make sure you get correct capitalisation, Simulator isn't case sensitive while iOS is case sensitive. That is more likely is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *drinksDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```